# Is there an issue with Eclipse plug in for Heroku?

Tags: heroku, eclipse-plugin

I m using Eclipse plugin to deploy new application on Heroku. However recently when I m trying to create a new app I get the following exception from Eclipse at the stage where I select a template app:

```
An unknown error has occurred. If this error persists, please follow up with Heroku support.
com.heroku.api.exception.RequestFailedException: Unexpected app exist status statuscode:401 responseBody:{"id":"unauthorized","error":"Unauthorized"}
```

I understand that it has to do with authorization. However I cannot find the way to check my credentials that I have provided to the Eclipse plugin. As far as I remeber the credentials are given during the next step , once you have selected and named your template app.

Anybody knows if there is a problem with eclipse plug in for heroku?

Thank you.

Comment: We may have had a temporary problem with the Heroku API, could you try again? It should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes everything is working fine now

Comment: @friism I think this problem is back again. I think it worked last Friday (12/7/13) but this week I get the same errors

Comment: When attempting to create an app from http://java.herokuapp.com/ its a similar problem: An `An error occurred cloning the app` error